# Covariance Estimation of time series with mixed frequencies

Tags: time-series, covariance-matrix, seasonality

I have three times series $x_{1,t}$, $x_{2,t}$ and $x_{3,t}$.
For the first two time series ($x_{1,t}$ and $x_{2,t}$) I have daily data, but for the last one, I have monthly data (let us assume that it is a daily process, but I can observe it only at month end).

How do I estimate the $3\times 3$ covariance matrix for the daily process ?

Comment: Two options: pairwise deletion and listwise deletion. See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/67528/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_details20.htm

Comment: I am aware of these two options. IMHO, listwise deletion is not desirable because it ignores too many data points. For the pairwise deletion, it does not guarantee the matrix will be positive semi-definite. Is there some method that does not ignore any data point and still provides an estimated covariance matrix that is positive semi-definite  ?

Comment: I do not think there are 3rd one.

Comment: You could use regularization or a Bayesian prior to maintain a SPD matrix.